# Low resolution of @2x images

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, retina

When I present my tableView with images on it, I see pixels on my images in spite of I'm using `@2x` at the end of file names.

I tried these cases:

1. I got from the server images URL with "@2x" as: https://mywebsite.com/images/logo@2x.png
2. I append "@2x" by myself as:

   ```
   var logo = String(website["logo"]) // logo.png
   let firstPart = logo.componentsSeparatedByString(".png")[0]
   logo = "\(firstPart)@2x.png"
   ```

But nothing changes, I see pixels on my images

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: what is the dimension of your `logo.png` and `logo@2x.png` ?

Comment: @Raptor the original size of my image is `260x260` and I put it into `38x38`

Comment: `@2x` should be exactly double width & height. Does not make sense to make such sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Actually source of pixelation is probably that your image's resolution is *too high*. Because when resolution is low image looks blurry not pixelated like in your case.

That means if your `UIImageView` is e.g 50x50, and you are trying to put there image 1000x1000 image *will* look pixelated. So try using images of proper size.

Comment: the original size of my image is `260x260` and I put it into `38x38`

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. Your image's resolution is too high.

Comment: So, I need make the original size `76x76` for this? Yes?

Comment: Okay, but if I'll make the original size as `114x114` and will use it for all cases @1x, @2x and @3x? Will it show pixels again in this case or or will be ok?

Comment: You can try this. But I suggest resizing image accordingly to display scale.

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade you should follow the size of `@1x` , `@2x` , `@3x` instead of using 1 size only

Comment: @Raptor but I get all images as a JSON from web. How can I implement it? So, one varian is detecting user's phone and concatenating "@2x" or "@3x" as I show above. Is it a correct way?

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade maybe [this tut](http://nshipster.com/image-resizing/) can help u with resizing, and u can detect 2x and 3x by detecting the brand or screen size